# C# iterator for async file copy

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Been running in circles to find the best solution for my client. We have a server that images are uploaded via ftp. I want to write an application that scans this server at frequent intervals and if it finds files it copies them to another,processing server.

So if during a time cycle, my app finds that there are 100 files, i want to start copying as many files as i can across to the processing server

i figured delegates would be the way to go but now i come across iterators...what do the experts say?

Well the ? really is - what is the fastest way to copy the files across servers?

Updated:
This may answer my ?..thanks all for playing
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337900.aspx)

Comment: ...and don't forget that variables are trendy these days as well. Now, excuse me, but what is the question, really?

Comment: Apples and oranges? Iterators and delegates? What is the question?

Comment: and I hear that extension properties are the wave of the future.

Comment: The fastest way to copy files accross servers is to increase your bandwidth: get gigabit ethernet or fiber-optic.

Comment: Lirik, the client don't wany pay mucho $$$

Comment: @uno you can't programatically increase your bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

Check out using the [FileSystemWatcher](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/article.php/c6043). Should make things easier. As far as coping them, check out [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(VS.71).aspx).

**foreach** the $h1t out of those files.

Check out this article on [Asynchronous File I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx)

Comment: Hunter: This is what they have right now and file copies take forever.....file size is 4-9Mb

Comment: FileSystemWatcher is lame. It can't even speed up the copy process.

Comment: @Musi... I think it was a good answer given the question... ya breakin' my balls

Comment: @uno is it a bandwidth issue? Is the code trying to copy all files at once or one at a time?

Comment: @Hunter: actually, I was breaking uno's balls with that comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

By far the slowest part of copying is going to be the copying itself. Don't worry about how long it takes to iterate the list of files.